# Apache Spark: is it possible to speed up some job by splitting dataset into several parts?

Tags: apache-spark

Given I have some long-running spark sql job.

Given I can split the input dataset into several parts and process the data incrementally (i.e. I am not using functions like median, min, max etc).

Under which conditions (meaning operators inside the query - joins of big tables, filtering, group by etc) such approach can have some benefits in terms of performance?

Comment: You can create partitions of data set and run them distributed. Partitioning definitely helps in improving parallelism. You can try Hash Partitioning or  Range Partitioning  based on your needs.

Comment: Aswath, I work with Hive tables, the data was partitioned somehow in advance. I cannot create additional Hive partitions by myself.

Comment: Depends on your workload, and if you have detailed example, show us.